# Hot Reloading Aframe from Vue CLI 3

Tags: vuejs2, aframe

I would like to be able to save my VueJS file and see the changes update in the Aframe output (Aframe component, textures, etc.).

I am currently using Vue CLI 3, and it has its own Webpack Dev Server setup. This works great for .Vue files, but when I have an `<a-entity/>` inside of a Vue component, it seems like the Aframe portion is not properly updated in the Aframe world.

For example, I have a fractal aframe component, and when I change the Vue file containing it, instead of it changing colors and animating, it turns blue and stops moving completely. I have to reload the page to see the change working.

I have tried to add the [aframe-super-hot-loader](https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-super-hot-loader) via a `vue.config.js` file, but no luck.

Here's my current `vue.config.js` setup, but not sure how to set this up, since .vue files contain HTML and JS...

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('aframe-hot-reload')
      .test(/\.vue|.js$/)
      .use('aframe-super-hot-loader')
      .loader('aframe-super-hot-loader')
      .end()
    config.module
      .rule('aframe-hot-reload')
      .test(/\.vue|.html$/)
      .use('aframe-super-hot-html-loader')
      .loader('aframe-super-hot-html-loader')
      .options({
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      })
      .end()
  }
}
```

This is what I would like to be able to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh_RQay3x80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue HTML is not HTML, it's a template that gets translated to JS. Vue has its own hot loaders. The A-Frame hot loader only works on actual HTML and A-Frame components. As usual, I don't recommend extra tooling/frameworks to prevent these sorts of confusion and missteps.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you point me towards a boilerplate for a solid A-Frame setup? I noticed you mentioned "I recommend using vanilla A-Frame and aframe-state-component with static templating" on A-frame React's Github, and would be curious to see an example of that. Been playing around with A-frame for the past few hours and it's really cool. Thanks!

Comment: I use something like this! https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-super-hot-loader/tree/master/example